# Programa com Warning e não realiza o que foi pedido

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Boa noite!
Quando estava estudando para a prova que realizarei, enfrentei essa pergunta.
Entretanto, quando realizado o programa, o mesmo teve warning e não realizou o que fiz.
Gostaria de que vissem meu código afim de entender melhor o meu erro. Desde já, muito obrigado.

> Faça um programa que leia o grau de instrução (tipo inteiro) e a idade
>   de um grupo de pessoas e exiba a idade do mais velho (considere que
>   não há empate) em cada grau de instrução. Término da leitura: grau de
>   instrução = 0. Tem-se os seguintes códigos de grau de instrução: 1 –
>   Analfabeto, 2 – Primeiro grau, 3 – Segundo grau, 4 – Superior, 5 –
>   Mestrado, 6 – Doutorado, 7 – Outros. Faça as seguintes funções: a)
>   inicializa(): recebe como parâmetro um vetor de números inteiros e
>   inicializa-o apropriadamente. 
>   b) exibe():recebe como parâmetro um
>   vetor de números inteiros já preenchido e exibe a idade do mais velho
>   (considere que não há empate) em cada grau de instrução.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TOT 7


void inicializa (int *vet){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < TOT; i++){
    }


}

void exibe (int *vet){
    int i;
    int velho;
    velho = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < TOT; i++){
        if (velho < vet[i])
            velho = vet[i];     
    }
    printf ("%d", velho);


}


int main (){
    int *vet[TOT], cont, idade, pessoas, instrucao;
    printf ("Digite a quantidade de pessoas\n");
    scanf ("%d", &pessoas);
    inicializa (vet);
    for (cont = 0; cont < pessoas;cont++){
        printf ("Digite o grau de instrucao\n");
        scanf ("%d", &instrucao);

        switch (instrucao)
        {
            case 1:
                printf ("Analfabeto");
                printf ("Digite sua idade");
                scanf ("%d", &idade);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf ("Primeiro Grau");
                printf ("Digite sua idade");
                scanf ("%d", &idade);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf ("Segundo grau");
                printf ("Digite sua idade");
                scanf ("%d", &idade);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf ("Superior");
                            printf ("Digite sua idade");
                scanf ("%d", &idade);
                break;
            case 5:
                printf ("Mestrado");
                            printf ("Digite sua idade");
                scanf ("%d", &idade);
                break;
            case 6:
                printf ("Doutorado");       
                    printf ("Digite sua idade");
                scanf ("%d", &idade);
                break;
            case 7:
                printf ("Outros");
                break;
                default:
                    printf ("opcao invalida");
                }
                exibe (vet);


        }
         return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Não seria para mostrar 7 valores a cada vez que `exibe` fosse chamada?

Answer (score 1):

`inicializa` teria que inicializar; não é o que você está fazendo aí!

```
void inicializa(int* v)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        v[i] = -1;
    }
}
```

Depois, `exibe` teria que mostrar o conteúdo do vetor,

```
void exibe(int* v)
{
    int i;

    printf("Maiores idades por grau de instrucao\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        if (v[i] == -1)
        {
            printf("%s: Nenhum informado\n", descricao(i + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s: %d\n", descricao(i + 1), v[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Criei uma função de apoio chamada `descricao`,

```
char* descricao(int grauInstrucao)
{
    switch (grauInstrucao)
    {
        case 1:
            return "Analfabeto(a)";
        case 2:
            return "Primeiro grau";
        case 3:
            return "Segundo grau";
        case 4:
            return "Ensino superior";
        case 5:
            return "Mestrado(a)";
        case 6:
            return "Doutorado(a)";
        case 7:
            return "Outros";
    }
}
```

`main` poderia ficar da seguinte forma:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int idadePorGrauInstrucao[7];
    int qtdPessoas;
    int grauInstrucao = -1;
    int i;
    int idade;

    inicializa(idadePorGrauInstrucao);

    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite a quantidade de pessoas: ");
        scanf("%d", &qtdPessoas);

        if (qtdPessoas > 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < qtdPessoas; ++i)
            {
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Digite o grau de instrucao da pessoa %d (0 para sair): ", i + 1);
                scanf("%d", &grauInstrucao);
                if (!grauInstrucao)
                {
                    break;
                }

                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Digite a idade: ");
                scanf("%d", &idade);
                if (idade >= 0)
                {
                    if (idadePorGrauInstrucao[grauInstrucao - 1] < idade)
                    {
                        idadePorGrauInstrucao[grauInstrucao - 1] = idade;
                    }
                }
            }

            exibe(idadePorGrauInstrucao);
        }
    } while (grauInstrucao);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado! É meio confuso vetores para mim ainda.

Answer (score 0):

1º - Você quer passar um vetor para uma função por referência então use isso:

```
int *vet, cont, idade, pessoas, instrucao;
printf ("Digite a quantidade de pessoas\n");
scanf ("%d", &pessoas);
inicializa (vet);
```

ou então...

```
int vet[TOT], cont, idade, pessoas, instrucao;

printf ("Digite a quantidade de pessoas\n");
scanf ("%d", &pessoas);
inicializa (&vet[0]);
```

No lugar disso:

```
int *vet[TOT];
```

2º - Observe que você não está inicializando os seus dados na função.

```
void inicializa (int *vet)
```